# C++ RTTI Inheritance causes class size to increase

Tags: c++, class, object, rtti

In C++ the problem is simple.

I have 2 classes one contains the other as part of its implementation.

```
struct A
{
    void do_something()
    {
    };
};

struct B
{
    A obj_A;
    void hello_world()
    {
    };
};
```

Now the problem is that structure B is one byte larger if A is part of B when I do a sizeof(B) and object of type B. A is 100% only going to include only non-virtual members (no virtual table required) and there is no need for a typeid check. Is there any way (like a compiler directive) to completely remove the unneeded byte from B but still access A's member function through B?

I can only assume the extra byte is a compiler added char* to A's name "A" but any other ideas can be helpful.

Comment: If your compiler is g++, try disabling RTTI by compiling with `g++ -fno-rtti`. If the problem persists, please give a full C++ source file which exhibits the problem, and I'll see what sizeof my compiler yields.

Comment: FWIW: I tried compiling your code with g++ (version 4.2.4) with and without the obj_A member, with and without RTTI enabled, and every time I got sizeof(B) == 1. So there appears to be some information missing from your question.

Answer (score 4):

sizeof(A) cannot be 0 because, each part of an object should be "adressable" (that is should have a different adress when we use operator &)

```
struct A
{
};

struct B
{
    A m_a1;
    A m_a2;
};

void test()
{
    B b;
    A* pa1 = &b.m_a1;
    A* pa2 = &b.m_a2;

    // "pa1" need to be different from "pa2" 
}
```

Comment: +1 Thats right. Also, every new of the class should return a different address so that use of delete will work properly. Thats the reason classes in C++ cannot have size = 0. Apart from this there are aspects of padding that a compiler may add to make the object align to the memory-word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention compilers, unfortunately.

Anyway, in the code you post, the class A is a candidate for the "Empty Base Class Optimization". Which is a part of the C++ standard that says that a base class with no member variables can be optimized away to take up no bytes.

B must by the C++ standard take up space, as it contains at least one member (namely obj_A).

You can access A's member function directly from within B, by calling do_something(). No magic is needed.

Comment: Is class A really considered a base class?

Comment: Yes, it it is also a leaf class

Comment: It may be a base class, but not B's base class.